# Javascript countdown timer to each html span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have programmatically created `<span>` tag in my html

I found simple example of javascript to do countdown timer

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

But this example let me use only one element

But i need to use this code like

```
<span onload="this.countdown(300)"></span>
```

So 300 is seconds which dynamically changing by my script

So after my script work i get on page

```
 <span onload="this.countdown(150)"></span>
 <span onload="this.countdown(3000)"></span>
 <span onload="this.countdown(4500)"></span>
 <span onload="this.countdown(600)"></span>
 <span onload="this.countdown(390)"></span>
```

So i need run all this timer at once, how to do that?

Comment: So 300 is seconds which dynamically changing by my script

Comment: Can you please share with us your main goal, what are you trying to achieve? I believe there's a better way of achieving what you want.

Comment: I generate span tags and need to run in each span countdown timer, each span  must countdown with it own second

Comment: I use this plugin, it's easy to use and work fine:  https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up

Comment: So, `countdown(150)` means count down to a 150 seconds from now? Or from a specific date?

Comment: It means countdown 150 seconds not from anything just 150 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
<div class="container">    
<span data-countdown="150"></span>
 <span data-countdown="3000" ></span>
 <span data-countdown="4500"></span>
 <span data-countdown="600"></span>
 <span data-countdown="390"></span>
</div>
```

on Script:

```
$('.container').load(function(){
var span =$(this).find('span');
span.countdown(span.attr('data-countdown'));
})
```

Note: look at logic only